# Parsing certain information from an html page

Tags: php, geolocation

I am trying to find a way to retrieve a users zip code based on their IP address. I would like to accomplish this without using a massive database. I found this script to get the state by IP, however I need it to grab the zipcode, I tried modifying the parameters of the strip_tags, but no dice.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$ip =$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$a=file("http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=$ip");
$zip=strip_tags($a[126]);
$zip=str_replace(" ","",$zip);
```

All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: That site doesn't seem to provide a ZIP code...

Comment: if you navigate to http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=76.10.46.12, you should see the "postal code" of 30260

Comment: It seems like there should be another source for this data than scraping it from a webpage.  I know MaxMind sells a web service that would be friendlier to parse, but there have got to be other good competitors too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the Postal Code at index `$a[134]`?

Comment: Odd, it was 133 on mine Maybe because I'm in the UK??

Comment: possibly ? when I tried 133, it came up literally with "Postal Code:"

Comment: You're right. I was running this on my localhost so I didn't get a value returned to see my mistake :o.